# Correct SQL Statement for duplicating items with special scenario

Tags: sql, reactjs, sqlite, duplicates, db-browser-sqlite

[image: SampleImage.jpg]

All check items in the picture must be shown.

Here is my sql statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.code || ' - ' || c.description || ' - ' || s.num AS SearchColumn, 
    s.num AS Num,
    c.code AS Code,
    c.product AS Product,
    f.faciltyname AS FacilityName,
    f.facilityid AS FacilityID,  
    c.description AS Description,  
    c.Number AS Num
FROM Facility f 
    JOIN Code c ON f.codeid = c.codeid
    JOIN Structure s ON c.structureid = s.structureid 
WHERE searchcolumn > "" 
    AND ((c.product = 'PROD1' OR c.product IS NULL )) 
ORDER BY c.code ASC
```

they were only duplicating from the code, the num and the productid (which also have special scenario) but actually it has different facilityid and facility name which is needed

Comment: Your sample data table does not agree with the query, and the former has fewer columns than the latter.  Please edit your question and make it reproducible.

Comment: actually that is not a sample table it is only a possible output. the columns there are only CODE, NUM, PRODUCT and FACILITY because it is the only columns where I should base the duplications, but I also need the other columns not stated in the picture